# Benefits and drawbacks of compartmentalizing functionality in a topical object file with functions interconnected by static (global) variables?

Tags: c

I have been thinking about this programming pattern lately because it looks smart and would solve many problems I have with having to carry variable pointers around or have return values just for the sake of being able to connect scopes.

Like everything, I am sure there are pitfalls and dangers associated with this, so I would like to expand my knowledge on the topic.

The idea is to put similar functions (for instance, to store some settings) into the same object file, and then have a static variable in that file that serves as a global connection between the functions. This compartmentalizes functionality, limits the scope of the global variable to only the functions using it, the access is faster since it is a global variable, and (most importantly), you can access this functionality from anywhere in the program and don't have to carry around structs and pointers just to be able to change a value.

Also, I'm not doing this in the library part of my code, but the executive part which is the actual program, so I would assume this is less bad.

The only other danger I know of is concurrency, but I think the previous point alleviates the concern since the program is created to be single-threaded.

Comment: Would this involve the loading of resources into memory that will not necessarily be used?

Comment: hmm. good question. I guess I could use this for loading as well. So let's say yes.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to do something like that (and common practice in low-end embedded systems). However the disadvantages are obvious: your code is essentially a "singleton", there can only exist one instance of it. Furthermore the code won't be thread safe unless you implement mutex or similar, which will be much worse for performance than passing the struct as parameter.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, but I'm implementing this at the code level, not at the library level, so my program is already designed to be single-threaded. I'm just taking advantage of a feature where I bundle similar stuff together. It's almost like making wrappers to simplify redundant or unchangeable parts of code. My understanding is that SDL2 organizes its library in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly your question is, but it looks like you are describing C modules, see e.g. here:

https://www.embedded.com/modular-programming-in-c/

I have been doing this for a few years now and am liking it more and more.

Comment: That's nothing unique to embedded systems, the article describes how you do C programming. Except that article seems kind of naive and informal, most professionals use code templates. Also the `extern` keyword is to be avoided like the plague, but that's another story.

Comment: Overall I'm not very impressed by embedded.com, I stopped reading that site many years ago. Most fresh out of school Computer Engineers could be teaching many of their article writers how to do embedded C programming... Designing programs by using private encapsulation shouldn't come as a big surprise to anyone who has studied programming proper.

Answer (score 1):

You can set global settings and, as long as you do not load unnecessary resources into memory, then it is feasible as well. For example, if you have a file that you might need to load into memory, then you could define a `file` value and a `getFile` function to get this value. So, when you call `getFile` for the first time, you would actually load the file from memory and store the result into `file`, later on, when you call `getFile` again, you will see it was already initialized so you will not need to load it from disk, but return the value of the variable itself.

You could use this pattern pretty consistently for your project, except for trivial settings that are small and easy to compute.

Benefit: you have an easier time while working.

Problem: it's not thread safe, so, you may want such a setting for each threads you use

Answer (score 0):

Using one set of global variables to pass information has several disadvantages:

1. It's not thread safe.
2. It creates a **huge** disconnect between the API as presented in header files and the actual data being passed around.  How would a programmer know that calling `void computeFoo()` passes data to `struct data *getBar()` in a completely separate source file?  "Oh, but we can put comments in the header file documenting the data flow".  And those comments will likely not be updated in `header.h` when the data flows in global variables between files `foo.c` and `bar.c` get updated, making the construct even **more** bug-prone.